# Is there a way to make VSCode/VScodium to just use CPU for rendering

Tags: visual-studio-code, rendering, vscodium

Is there a way to force VSCode to use CPU/SW rendering?

I am currently working with 3D graphics program (Daz Studio), it extensively uses GPU for asset rendering and needs every bit of my 6GB GPU memory. I mainly use browser, VSCodium and Daz Studio. I have already switched my browsers to use only CPU (i.e Software rendering) which saves me 200-300MB of GPU memory, I want to do the same with VSCode which would free up 200MB more. Is this possible?

I tried to look around the settings but I could force the "Terminal" to use CPU but it did not help much.

Answer (score 3):

You can edit your `~/.vscode/argv.json` file and uncomment the line that says "`"disable-hardware-acceleration": true`":

```json
// Use software rendering instead of hardware accelerated rendering.
// This can help in cases where you see rendering issues in VS Code.
// "disable-hardware-acceleration": true,
```

See the docs for more info: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_disable-gpu-acceleration. Quoting from those docs:

> We have heard issue reports from users that seem related to how the GPU is used to render VS Code's UI. These users have a much better experience when running VS Code with the additional `--disable-gpu` command-line argument. Running with this argument will disable the GPU hardware acceleration and fall back to a software renderer.
>
> To make life easier, you can add this flag as a setting so that it does not have to be passed on the command line each time.
>
> To add this flag:
>
> - Open the Command Palette (`Ctrl+Shift+P`).
> - Run the **Preferences: Configure Runtime Arguments** command.
> - This command will open a `argv.json` file to configure runtime arguments. You might see some default arguments there already.
> - Add `"disable-hardware-acceleration": true`.
> - Restart VS Code.
>
> **Note:** Do not use this setting unless you are seeing issues!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, After some digging into vscode's repo I figured that we can pass the argument "--disable-gpu" on the executable, this prevents VSCode from using the GPU.

I directly edited this to codium.bat Example : "%~dp0..\VSCodium.exe" "%~dp0..\resources\app\out\cli.js" --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node %* **--disable-gpu**

Still I could not find a built in setting to do this, for now I am use this workaround.

Update : Hopefully there will a UI option in future ticked submitted at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/174936